# Unable to create account in magento 2.2.10

Tags: magento2, customer-account

Unable to create account. It refresh the register form without any response

Comment: Have you tried with default Magento theme or any custom theme?

Comment: tried with both but not able to create

Comment: did you checked exception.log or system.log file?.

Comment: @NareshRupareliya yes..!

Comment: any exception is there?

Comment: @NareshRupareliya No exception...!

Comment: after refreshing of page any message display on page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102102/discussion-between-akash-killedar-and-naresh-rupareliya).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your base URL in `core_config_data` table in database

> from : http://localhost:8888/magento
>
> to : http://127.0.0.1:8888/magento

Hope this will help you!